# Diferença entre seletor.classe e .classe seletor

Tags: html, css, classes

Olá, pessoal. Sou iniciante em programação e estou com uma dúvida em CSS. Em um código aonde quero que todos os H5 que possuam a classe .special sejam vermelhos, há alguma diferença entre h5.special e .special h5? Usando h5.special, consegui o que queria, mas usando .special h5, não obtive o mesmo resultado. Por que? Quando devo utilizar o seletor após a classe e o inverso?

HTML:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css"  href="style.css"/>
    </head>
 <body>
        <h5 class="special"> Destino </h5>
        <br> texto texto texto texto texto texto <br>
        <br> texto texto texto texto texto texto <br>

        <h5>Destino </h5>
        <br> texto texto texto texto texto texto <br>
        <br> texto texto texto texto texto texto <br>

        <h5 class="special"> Destino</h5>
        <br> texto texto texto texto texto texto <br>
        <br> texto texto texto texto texto texto <br>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h5.special {
color: red;
}
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0):

.special H5 quer dizer: nas H5 que estejam dentro de .special deve ser red

```
<h5>Cor padrão</h5>
<div class="special">
<h5>Aqui deve aparecer vermelho</h5>
</div>
```